# Java Midi - How To Create Midi Events / Record from Java Synth to Java Sequencer?

Tags: java, midi

I will start off by explicitly stating my main question: what is the correct way to create midi events with the correct 'tick' from ShortMessages with the correct microsecond position when using the Java synthesizer to record to the Java sequencer?

I've been trying to figure this out for several days. My little midi program is quite simple, or should be, at least. There's a piano layout and three buttons. The piano, which uses the synthesizer, works great; you can play notes with the mouse or your computer keyboard.

I've read the Oracle Docs instructions backwards and forwards (and lots of forum threads), but clearly I'm missing something.

Currently I can get the sequencer to record by manually creating a ShortMessage, a MidiEvent, and sending them to the sequencer/add them to the track, but it will only record once. The play back also plays them back with usually the wrong timing. Here's the code that executes these: (if you want me to post additional or all of the code let know).

The code for what happens when I click the record/stop/buttons:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand() == "Record")
    {

        mySeq.deleteTrack(track);
        track = mySeq.createTrack();
        try {
            seq.setSequence(mySeq);
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        seq.recordEnable(track, ChannelNum);
        seq.startRecording();
    }

    else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Stop")
    {
        seq.stop();
    }

    else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Play")
    {
        mySeq.deleteTrack(track);
        track = mySeq.createTrack();
        addEvents(track);
        seq.setTickPosition(10);
        seq.start();
    }

}
```

This is the code for when the user plays a note on the piano:

```
    // The Mouse presses a key, the note on the channel is turned on
    // A MidiEvent and ShortMessage are created using the CreateOnEvent method
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
        Key key = (Key) e.getSource ();
        channel.noteOn (key.getNote (), 127);
        CreateOnEvent(key);
    }

    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) {
        Key key = (Key) e.getSource ();
        channel.noteOff (key.getNote ());
        CreateOffEvent(key);
    }

    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e) { }
```

And finally here's the CreateOnEvent Method:

```
    // I originally was sending the events directly to the sequencer
    // but here I'm adding the events to an ArrayList of MidiEvents to attempt a work around
    // I can then add those events to a track to play them
    public void CreateOnEvent(Key key)
{
    if(seq.isRecording())
    {
        ShortMessage myMsg = new ShortMessage();
        try {
            myMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, ChannelNum, key.getNote(), 127);
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeStamp = synth.getMicrosecondPosition();
        long tick = seq.getTickPosition();
        event = new MidiEvent(myMsg, tick);
        seqReceiver.send(myMsg, timeStamp);
        Events.add(event);
    }

}
```